# Android: Gregorian Calendar issue

Tags: java, android, datetime, gregorian-calendar

I am getting confuse with using Gregorian.

I am using GregorianCalendar to get the current date and setting the future date.

The current month : it prints me the month as 8 rather 9 where 9 is my expected month.
The current year : it prints me the year in 2011 which is correct.

What is going wrong.

The code I use is GregorianCalender.getInstance(); to get the current date.

Comment: Did you read [its Javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) about the month field? It's 0-based. After all, you should use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to convert a calendar/date to a human readable and printable string.

Comment: Oh thanks. I saw the date class use year start from 0 in 1900 and month is 0-11 but why does GregorianCalendar was not the same on year as the date.

Answer (score 0):

Using the jdk's calendar is a little confusing and you'll have to write a lot of code. Instead try a library called joda - 
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/